# Calling a function after checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a form with several checkboxes. A message on the right side is shown or hidden after selecting or deselecting a checkbox.

I am new to C# and I am wondering if I can do this with something similar to JavaScript:

```
function check() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
}

function uncheck() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, not much point to them if you could not: [Responding to Windows Forms CheckBox Clicks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983710(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Have you tried looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx#Events)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy: I double clicked on the checkbox and added this script:

```
private void checkBox_AllData_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox_AllData.Checked == true)
    {
        AllDataAlertIcon.Visible = true;
        AllDataAlertText.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (checkBox_AllData.Checked == false)
    {
        AllDataAlertIcon.Hide();
        AllDataAlertText.Hide();
    }
}
```